# Display one polyline of leaflet map with two different colors in shiny

Tags: shiny, leaflet, polyline

Is there any way to display one polyline with two different colours(ex: based on road speed limit) in leaflet by using shiny? Any help could be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this plugin : http://hgoebl.github.io/Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline/demo/

You will have to define the speed for each point in your GeoJSON properties.

Then you simply have to add this code after :

```
var myPolyline = L.multiOptionsPolyline(YourGeoJSONHere, {
    multiOptions: {
        optionIdxFn: function (latLng) {
            var i,
                speedThresholds = [5, 10, 15, 30];

            for (i = 0; i < speedThresholds.length; ++i) {
                if (latLng.alt <= speedThresholds[i]) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return speedThresholds.length;
        },
        options: [
            {color: '#0000FF'}, {color: '#0040FF'},
            {color: '#0080FF'}, {color: '#00FFB0'}
        ]
    },
    weight: 5,
    opacity: 0.9,
    smoothFactor: 1
}).addTo(layerTrace);
```

For the speed : https://github.com/hgoebl/Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline/blob/master/demo/js/demo.js#L59-L80